# enterprise library causes slowness?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, enterprise-library

I have added Enterprise Libarary cache to my web application.

My web-services becomes really slow after few hundreds of requests (simulated with fiddler).

after a few hours the performance is good again.

does this can lead me to think of caching issues?

Is there any smart tool or and idea how to investigate this in a smart way?

I see the CPU gets very high (90%) because of my iis-process

Comment: a memory profiler; a code profiler; perfmon; adplus + windbg

Comment: any free code profiler?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx

Comment: can prefmon help me monitor the cache? what counters should I use?